# Can word2vec model be used for words also as training data instead of sentences

Tags: word2vec, nlp

In Word2vec can we use words instead of sentences for model training

Like below code gberg_sents is sentence tokens
model = Word2Vec(sentences=gberg_sents,size=64,sg=1,window=10,min_count=5,seed=42,workers=8)

Like this can we use word tokens also

Comment: It's not clear what you mean. The `sentences` parameter just needs to be an (re-)iterable sequence, where each item is a list-of-words. (Is that what `gberg_sents` is in your example? Show how it's created or some example items.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, word2vec is trained with a language modeling objective, i.e., it predicts what words appear in surrounding of other words. For this, your training data need to be actual sentences that show how the words are used in context. It is actually the context of the words that gives you the information that is captured in the embeddings.